# Was bedeutet Schellenberg?

Tags: dictionary, quotes

Ich habe in diesen Kontext das Wort gefunden:

> Die relativ offen gestalteten Zaunelemente ermöglichen auch Kindern
>   einen direkten Blick ins Gehege und schaffen, so Schellenberg, "eine
>   gefühlte Offenheit"

1.- Was bedeutet Schellenberg?

2.- Warum ist "eine gefühlte Offenheit" in Anführungszeichen?

Comment: In dieser Konstruktion bedeutet "so" so viel wie "sagte".

Comment: Der Satz ist ungünstig konstruiert (Komma). Man würde die Anführungsstriche eigentlich weglassen können und es wäre auch dann klar, daß Schellenberg das gesagt hat. Die Anführungsstriche untermauern vlt. das exakte Zitat.

Comment: @Thomas: Das sehe ich nicht so; ein Konjunktiv für indirekte Rede wäre dann schon angebracht.

Comment: @guidot Ein Konjunktiv in "eine gefühlte Offenheit"?

Comment: @guidot   Er meint wohl: *... und **schafften**, so Schellenberg, eine gefühlte Offenheit.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"eine gefühlte Offenheit" ist in Anführungszeichen, weil es ein Zitat ist. Zitiert wird jemand namens Schellenberg.

> Die relativ offen gestalteten Zaunelemente ... schaffen "eine gefühlte Offenheit", sagt Schellenberg,